# nodejs wont allow non local connections

Tags: node.js, django, express, nodejs-express-server

-If I serve the same app on the same port with something else like django, it works

-I can curl and get a response from the node app if I curled from the server itself (as if it was served on localhost).

-app.js is simply this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

-runs express

-I want to see it from any machine connected to the internet, not just from the server

Comment: Do you even know if port 8080 on this computer is actually reachable from the internet?  If so, are you using a raw IP address or a DNS name?  What is the type of network location of this computer?  Home computer behind a home router?  Shared hosting in a data-center?  Dedicated hosting?

Comment: yes, and i tried other ports too, but as i said, i ran a django server on 8080 and it worked.

Comment: There has to be some other difference between your Express server on 8080 and your DJango server on 8080 than what you're claiming.  A port is a port.  If your express server is actually running on port 8080 and port 8080 is reachable as you claim, then the express server would be able to work too.

Comment: Yea, I realized that the problem was actually on the client side. The server was fine. As expected, the port is a port and nothing was wrong with either of my servers. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

replace `app.listen(8080)` to `app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0')`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you didn't expect localhost to be internet visible by default :)

The easiest way to do this would be to deploy your app to one of the platform services available. [Heroku](http://heroku.com) is a good choice for node.js that offers a free plan.

On the other hand, if you just want to test things out, [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) is a handy tool that can make your localhost:port visible to the internet via a generated URL like http://{hash}.ngrok.com.

Comment: app.listen(8080); makes it not localhost, that's for sure. Trust me, it's public. Secondly, I really rather node be deployed on my server alone, sorry for being impossible.